# Custom navigationItem.titleView not setting

Tags: ios, swift

I am having troubles setting the `self.navigationItem.titleView`, could someone please help me catch my mistake.

```
import Foundation

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let logo = UIImage(named: "browse_back")
        var hexColor = 0x21BBD4 as UInt
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = GeneralHelper.UIColorFromRGB(hexColor)
        self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: logo)
    }
}
```

Here is my code for setting the titleView to an image.

[image]
[image]

When I run the application, the color of the navigation bar is being changed to the correct color, but the titleView image is not displaying.

- I've tested to ensure the image does exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The managing `UINavigationController` object uses the navigation items
>   of the topmost two view controllers to populate the navigation bar
>   with content.

Source: [UINavigationItem Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html)

You have to set the `titleView` of the `navigationItem` of the controller that is the top most controller in the navigation stack managed by your custom navigation controller.

Comment: Ah so, this would mean aI wouldn't get setting it in the Navigation Controller, but the first controller in the navigation controller stack? Edit: Worked. Sweet thanks for the help, I will it mark it as the answer.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You set it in the controller that is pushed on the stack.

Comment: Also try specifying a size for the Frame of the UIView you add.

Answer (score 6):

For those using a UILabel as your titleView

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    navigationItem.titleView?.sizeToFit()
}
```

Hope this works!